# Maximum size of minimal generating set for $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Consider all [minimal generating sets](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimal_generating_set) for $S_n$. The smallest of them have size 2, that is, $S_n$ can be generated by two permutations. What are the largest ones?

As I understand, there should exist minimal generating sets of size $n - 1$. E.g. the Coxeter generating set $(1\;2),\, (2\;3),\, \dots,\, (n - 1\;n)$ appears to be minimal: if we remove any single permutation $(i\;i + 1)$, then $S_i \times S_{n-i}$ will be generated. And also $(1\;2),\, (1\;3),\, \dots,\, (1\;n)$ appears to be minimal: without any single permutation, $S_{n-1}$ will be generated.

Is it true that a minimal generating set for $S_n$ cannot have more than $n - 1$ elements? Is it somehow related to [Jerrum's filter](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Jerrum_filter) that is guaranteed to return a generating set of size $\le n - 1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximal size of an irredundant generating set of $S_n$ is proved to be $n-1$ in the paper

Julius Whiston, Maximal Independent Generating Sets of the Symmetric
Group, Journal of Algebra 232, 255-268 (2000).

You can find this online by searching for it.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.2000.8399

Comment: Thanks! Among the papers referencing Whiston 2000, I also found [Cameron & Cara 2002](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-8693(02)00550-1) and [Egri-Nagy & Gebhardt 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03957) helpful for me.