# Minimal generating set in case of finite non-abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated

Finding a minimal generating set of a finite group is difficult but in the case of abelian groups using the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, we can find it easily. Moreover, corresponding to each $k\in \mathbb N$, we have an abelian group such that the cardinality of a minimal generating set is $k$ (take rank $k$ abelian groups). In the case of non-abelian groups, we know that symmetric group on $n$-letters $S_{n}$ can be generated by two elements. Can you give an example of a finite non-abelian group that cannot be generated by two elements? In general, can we find a nonabelian group corresponding to each $k>1$ such that the cardinality of a minimal generating set is $k$?

Thank you.

Comment: Look up a wiki about the Burnside Problem and Burnside Groups. For example https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Burnside_group

Comment: Or see here for examples https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380840/can-a-direct-product-of-nonabelian-simple-groups-be-generated-by-two-elements

Comment: Perhaps the simplest examples are the [extraspecial groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_special_group) of order $p^{2n+1}$, where $p$ is a prime, all of whose minimal generating sets have order $2 n$. A central product of such a group by a cyclic group of order $p^{2}$ allows you to get odd numbers of generators as well.

Comment: "Minimal generating set" is ambiguous. Minimal with respect to inclusion or cardinality.?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you for the answer. One more example I am thinking of: What can we say about a minimal generating set of direct products of an abelian group of rank $k$ and a finite non-abelian group(like any symmetric group)? Clearly, the group is non-abelian. Can we comment on its minimal generating set now?

Comment: @DerekHolt I am using this definition. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimal_generating_set#:~:text=A%20generating%20set%20of%20a,dropped%20from%20the%20generating%20set.

Comment: Isn't $S_n\times (\mathbb{Z}_p)^k$ (for some prime $p$ not dividing $n!$) generated by $k+2$ elements and not less? And yet nonabelian.

Comment: @Kavita That definition is minimal with respect to inclusion. That makes your question easier because, for example, $S_n$ has minimal sets of different cardinalities, in fact all $k$ with $2 \le k \le n-1$.

Comment: @freakish I am thinking the same. Not sure! How to prove it if it is exactly $k+2$ not less?

Comment: @Kavita Not sure how to prove what? AndreasCaranti has explained how to do this in his comment.

Comment: @Kavita, if $A$ is a finite abelian group with minimal number of generators $k$, and $S$ is a non-abelian group, then a minimal generating set of $G = A \times S$ has at least $k$ elements, as such a set projects onto a set of generators of $G/S \cong A$. However, if $A$ is elementary abelian of order $2^6$ (so $k = 6$ here), one can check that when $S = A_{4}$ then the minimal number of generators of $G$ is $6$, and when $S = S_{4}$ the number is $7$.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the following definition:

> A *minimal generating set* for a group $G$ is a set $S$ such that $\langle S\rangle = G$, but for every proper subset $T$ of $S$, $\langle T\rangle\neq G$.

As Derek Holt points in comments, this makes an affirmative answer to your question easy: the set
$$\{(1,2), (1,3),\ldots,(1,k-1), (1,k), (1,k+1)\}$$
is a minimal generating set with $k$ elements for $S_{k+1}$.

In fact, $S_n$ has minimal generating sets of sizes $k$, $2\leq k\leq n-1$: the set $\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),\ldots,(1,k),(k,k+1,\ldots,n)\}$ is easily verified to a minimal generating set.

Moreover, as noted in [comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3993760/742), it is a theorem that if a finite group $G$ has a minimal generating set with $k$ elements, and a minimal generating set with $\ell\gt k$ elements, then it has minimal generating sets with $m$ elements for all $m$, $k\leq m\leq\ell$. This is Tarski's Irredundant Basis Theorem. See references cited in [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/226661/3959) about the values of $D(G)$, the size of the largest possible minimal generating set for $G$.

On the other hand, given a finite group $G$, if we let $d(G)$ denote the cardinality of the *smallest* minimal generating set for $G$ (also called the "rank of $G$" or the "generating rank of $G$"), you might ask whether for any $k>1$ there exists a finite nonabelian group such that $d(G)=k$. Again, as noted in the comments, an extra-special $p$-group ($p\gt 2$) of order $p^{2n+1}$ has generating rank $2n$, and then taking the direct product with a cyclic group of order $p$ gives a group with generating rank $2n+1$, so the answer is "yes" here as well.